# Check if an html button was clicked

Tags: javascript, storage, local

I'm a little confused on a programming assignment that I have. I need to make the button so that when the page is loaded, local storage will detect if the user clicked the button on the last time the page was loaded. If the user has clicked the button, if should give an alert statement saying they've clicked the button. If not, the alert should say that they haven't clicked the button. What I'm asking is, is there a way to check and see if an htm button was clicked on the previous page load? Thank you.

Comment: You could use a cookie.

Comment: No. We learned how to do the local storage and set it up to retain values. On top of that, he wants us to do a check for values. There's nothing in the lecture notes about this, and I've searched the book. Any advice would be great please.

Comment: please provide code and point where are you stuck at?

Comment: You know how to save a value in local storage, and you know how to get it out.  This is 90% of the solution.  The other 10% is knowing when the button is clicked and when the page is loaded.  Do you need help with these?

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no 'native' way to check if an html button was clicked on the previous page load.  You can sortof(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Privacy_and_the_:visited_selector) check if a link has been visited with the :visited css selector, but that isn't what you want anyways, because it would persist for more than one page view.

Probably the best thing to do is:

1. When the page is loaded, check local storage to see if some value is set (i.e. linkVisited)

   a. If it has been visited, bind an event on 'click' of the link, and display an alert saying 'link already visited'.

   b. If the has not been visited, bind an event on 'click' of the link, and set a value in local storage (i.e. linkVisited) before following the link (window.location = link href).
2. After binding the appropriate event clear any existing value in the localstorage, so that subsequent refreshes will proceed to 1.b instead of 1.a

Answer (score 0):

WITH LOCAL STORAGE 
**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ubeleh/2/)**

HTML

```
<body onload="checkCookie()">
    <input type="button" value="Click ME" onclick="addCookie()">
</body>
```

Script

```
function checkCookie()
{

    var username= localStorage.getItem("buttonClicked");


      if (username!=null && username!="" )
      {
          alert("Button Clicked");
           localStorage.removeItem("buttonClicked");
      }
      else 
      {
          alert("Button Not Clicked");
      }

}
function addCookie(){
   localStorage.setItem("buttonClicked","true");

}
```

WITH COOKIE
**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ubeleh/1)**

HTML

```
<body onload="checkCookie()">
    <input type="button" value="Click ME" onclick="addCookie()">
</body>
```

Script

```
function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{
    var exdate=new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

function getCookie(c_name)
{
    var c_value = document.cookie;
    var c_start = c_value.indexOf(" " + c_name + "=");
    if (c_start == -1)
      {
      c_start = c_value.indexOf(c_name + "=");
      }
    if (c_start == -1)
      {
      c_value = null;
      }
    else
      {
      c_start = c_value.indexOf("=", c_start) + 1;
      var c_end = c_value.indexOf(";", c_start);
      if (c_end == -1)
      {
    c_end = c_value.length;
    }
    c_value = unescape(c_value.substring(c_start,c_end));
    }
    return c_value;

}

function checkCookie()
{

    var username=getCookie("buttonClicked");
      if (username!=null && username!="")
      {
          alert("Button Clicked");
          setCookie("buttonClicked",null,-365);// RESET Cookie
      }
      else 
      {
          alert("Button Not Clicked");
      }

}
function addCookie(){
    setCookie("buttonClicked","true",365);
}
```

Comment: Why give a cookie based solution when the OP specified localStorage?

Comment: @idbentley  updated answer to show both implementations Cookie and LocalStorage

Answer (score -1):

You can, if you want to avoid cookie, do a trick:

You can add to this button click event a function that edit a form's field and then, instead of just reload the page, you send this form ,to the same page (get method), then you can easily get the value of click from the url (the form can be hidden, so the user can't see it).
onload (also the first time) the checkme function add the 'no' value to the url, so, if you send or reload the page, the alert shows 'no'. if you click the button the url value is changed and, if you reload the page or send the form, the alert show the' yes' value.

This works, yes it can be hacked, but works without cookie

```
<body onload="checkme(document.URL)">
<script>
function checkme(ur){
    var interesting = ur.split('?');
    if(typeof(interesting[1]) != 'undefined'){
        var more_interesting = interesting[1].split('=');
        alert(more_interesting[1]);
        document.getElementById('myfieldhidden').value='no';
            window.history.replaceState('Object', 'Title', '?clicked=no');
    }else{
        //first load
        window.history.replaceState('Object', 'Title', '?clicked=no');
    }
}
function func2(){
        window.history.replaceState('Object', 'Title', '?clicked=ye');  
}
</script>

<button onclick="document.getElementById('myfieldhidden').value='ye';func2()"></button>

<form title="myformsecret" action="" id="myformsecret" method="get">
<input name="clicked" id="myfieldhidden" value="nop"/>
</form>

<a href="javascript:document.getElementById('myformsecret').submit()">send me when you want</a>
</body>
```

Comment: Op want the alert the next time page is visited. not necessarily immidately or via a link.. it should work even when page refresh.

Comment: @rahulmaindargi infact, if you test this code, it works. The first time the page is loaded, it do nothing, the second time, even if the button was not clicked, the alert appear. Please be careful before to vote or comment something you didn't tryed yet!

Comment: you code works only in 1 scenario... try these steps.. and it wont work
1. Load page... 2. Click Button..3. Refresh Page... (NEVER CLICK the link...)

basically your code works only if user clicks on Link.. not on button..

Comment: You was right @rahulmaindargi, sorry. I made some little changes and now it works, so please, let's do the right thing.